# Making Data.Lazy.Map an instance of Num

Tags: haskell

In a project I need quite often to sum up lists and hash. I ended up with the two following declarations of `Num` instances

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
module Tweak where
import Data.List
import qualified Data.Map.Lazy as M
import Control.Applicative

instance (Applicative f, Num b) => Num (f b) where
  negate      = fmap negate
  (+)         = liftA2 (+)
  (*)         = liftA2 (*)
  fromInteger = pure . fromInteger
  abs         = fmap abs
  signum      = fmap signum

instance (Ord k, Num b) => Num(M.Map k b) where
  negate      = fmap negate
  (+)         = M.unionWith (+)
  (*)         = M.unionWith (*)
  fromInteger = undefined
  abs         = fmap abs
  signum      = fmap signum
```

Running this `(M.fromList [(2 :: Int, 3 :: Int)]) + (M.fromList [(1, 2)])`
 in ghci produces the following error

```
<interactive>:2:37:
    Overlapping instances for Num (M.Map Int Int)
      arising from a use of ‘+’
    Matching instances:
      instance (Ord k, Num b) => Num (M.Map k b)
        -- Defined at Tweak.hs:15:10
      instance (Applicative f, Num b) => Num (f b)
        -- Defined at Tweak.hs:7:10
    In the expression:
      (M.fromList [(2 :: Int, 3 :: Int)]) + (M.fromList [(1, 2)])
    In an equation for ‘it’:
        it = (M.fromList [(2 :: Int, 3 :: Int)]) + (M.fromList [(1, 2)])
```

If I understand the error Haskell believes that `M.Map Int` is an instance of `Applicative`. Which seems not to be the case. `:i M.Map Int` yields

```
type role M.Map nominal representational
data M.Map k a
  = containers-0.5.6.2:Data.Map.Base.Bin {-# UNPACK #-}containers-0.5.6.2:Data.Map.Base.Size
                                         !k
                                         a
                                         !(M.Map k a)
                                         !(M.Map k a)
  | containers-0.5.6.2:Data.Map.Base.Tip
    -- Defined in ‘containers-0.5.6.2:Data.Map.Base’
instance (Ord k, Num b) => Num (M.Map k b)
  -- Defined at Tweak.hs:15:10
instance (Eq k, Eq a) => Eq (M.Map k a)
  -- Defined in ‘containers-0.5.6.2:Data.Map.Base’
instance Functor (M.Map k)
  -- Defined in ‘containers-0.5.6.2:Data.Map.Base’
instance (Ord k, Ord v) => Ord (M.Map k v)
  -- Defined in ‘containers-0.5.6.2:Data.Map.Base’
instance (Ord k, Read k, Read e) => Read (M.Map k e)
  -- Defined in ‘containers-0.5.6.2:Data.Map.Base’
instance (Show k, Show a) => Show (M.Map k a)
  -- Defined in ‘containers-0.5.6.2:Data.Map.Base’
instance Foldable (M.Map k)
  -- Defined in ‘containers-0.5.6.2:Data.Map.Base’
instance Traversable (M.Map k)
  -- Defined in ‘containers-0.5.6.2:Data.Map.Base’
instance Ord k => Monoid (M.Map k v)
  -- Defined in ‘containers-0.5.6.2:Data.Map.Base’
data Ability = ... | Int | ...  -- Defined at Character.hs:60:41

data Int = GHC.Types.I# GHC.Prim.Int#   -- Defined in ‘GHC.Types’
instance Bounded Int -- Defined in ‘GHC.Enum’
instance Enum Int -- Defined in ‘GHC.Enum’
instance Eq Int -- Defined in ‘GHC.Classes’
instance Integral Int -- Defined in ‘GHC.Real’
instance Num Int -- Defined in ‘GHC.Num’
instance Ord Int -- Defined in ‘GHC.Classes’
instance Read Int -- Defined in ‘GHC.Read’
instance Real Int -- Defined in ‘GHC.Real’
instance Show Int -- Defined in ‘GHC.Show’
```

I really don't understand this error. Any help will be very welcome.

Comment: Haskell performs instance resolution before looking at constraints, so you have actually defined an instance `forall f b. Num (f b)`, which is extremely general, and probably isn’t what you want. Constraints are only checked *after* an instance is chosen.

Comment: Yes this is surely not what I want. Any idea how to solve this ?

Comment: It may be what you are asking for, but delivering what you ask for here, comes at a high high cost. No other Num instances on anything of kind * -> *. A better mechanism is to make a `newtype ANum f a = ANum (f a)` and then bake your instance into the newtype. Then you don't conflict with every other possible num instance on something of kind * -> * anybody will ever write, and users can wrap up their data into a form compatible with your usecases. Consider `newtype Poly a = Poly [a]` it will overlap with your instance, but certainly shouldn't be done using the applicative for []`!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do people always think that it's a good idea to define this kind of instances?

Type classes are all about allowing to *safely write generic functions*. This works by specifying certain methods *and clear laws about how they should play together*. Like, the monad laws etc..
`Num` basically represents the mathematical concept of a [ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_(mathematics)), plus a somewhat halfheartedly-done approach to define a [metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_space). This only works well if you actually limit it to *number types*. General *collections of numbers*, like with your `Applicative` instance, may not obey these laws at all.

So, just stay away from such instances. I suspect the way you're trying to use them has nothing to do with generic algorithms anyway... if you just want to have a consise operator name for `M.unionWith (+)` then you're abusing type classes. You can just define a plain monomorphic operator `(+<)` (or, at least, not ad-hoc-polymorphic – it's probably ok if it works on `(Num n, Ord k) => M.Map k n`) or something like that.

If you think you do need class polymorphism, then look for the right classes! [`Additive`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/linear-1.20.5/docs/Linear-Vector.html#t:Additive) might make sense. And behold, [it actually has an instance for `Map`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/linear-1.20.5/docs/src/Linear-Vector.html#line-269) already...

---

I should mention a third possibility, which is actually what I normally recommend *and* is in a sense closer to your `Num` instance ideas: the [`VectorSpace` class](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-space-0.10.2/docs/Data-VectorSpace.html). Like `Num`, this is actually a class of value-types, not of functors, but unlike `Num` it doesn't have that `abs` etc. fuzz.

Unlike `Additive`, this package doesn't ship with a `Map` instance, but there's [a dedicated type](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-space-map-0.2.0/docs/Data-Map-Vector.html) for just tha And a function instance is standard, so, with vector-space's `^+^` you can in fact add up `a -> Map k Int` values.

Comment: My declaration of `Num` for `Applicative` is canonical. I lift the numerical operation on a pointwise way.
`M.Map k n` is just a function from `k` to `n` so it also makes perfect sense to define the operation point-wise on it.
Looking closer at the code in `Additive` the declaration for `M.Map` is pretty similar to mine. However I don't like because it gives `M.Map Int Char` an addition which makes no sense to me.
Also I do not refer to the Ring structure, I see `Num` as a low-level category that allows the computer to perform basic computations on those object which is exactly what I want.

Comment: How is `Num` a [category](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_(mathematics))? That really doesn't make sense to me. — `Additive` doesn't give `Map Int Char` an addition, what gave you that impression? It only lifts `Num` instances to pointwise-Num operations within some functor, i.e. exactly what you need.

Comment: Well `Num` is collections of sets so I've got the habit of calling it a category even in this case the morphisms are trivial.
I got this feeling because of the declaration `instance Ord k => Additive (Map k) where` which made me think that `Map Int b` should be additive for any `b`. But I understood why I was wrong.
Haskell syntax is still a bit unfamiliar for me so it took me a while to understand what this was actually doing and this is pretty elegant. Thank you for pointing out!

Comment: In fact the answer is only partially satisfactory. I can indeed add up to `Map k Int` by using `^+^` but I cannot add up functions `a -> Map k Int` while a proper lift would authorize me to do it. Do you have any workaround ?